# Parenting objects while still keeping Order in Outliner

Tags: workflow, parent, outliner

Is there a way to parent object while still keeping the order in the outliner? when I parent object from multiple collections to an object, the whole order gets destroyed. [image: Before and After Parenting]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects which have their parent in the same collection are placed under their parent in the hierarchy, and their are not re-drawn anywhere else in the collection. You can also see a parent's children that are not in the same collection with their icon and name faded-out.

To disable this behaviour, uncheck "Object children" in the outliner filter (The sieve icon in the upper right of the outliner editor)

[image]